# How to read from an MSI file in chunks via the API?

Tags: windows-installer

The [ReadStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371140%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API of the Record object in the MSI COM API reads all of the data of a record. If a record is very very large, this can be, well, inconvenient. It seems strange that there is no mechanism to read progressive chunks. Is there some other path to this data that we're missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do successive calls to that API without changing the field return successive chunks of the stream? That's approximately how the underlying C++ API [MsiRecordReadStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370370%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) works, and ReadStream appears to be a simple projection of the C++ API.